# Crypto Node.js : PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128

Tags: node.js, cryptography, cryptojs

I am trying to implement an equivalent of PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128 crypt algorithm from Java for a node.js project.

I basically need to encrypt a string using a cipher made by that algorithm.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is the snippet of code I have written in Java

```
public final static String ALGO_VIDEO_ENCRYPTOR = "PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128";
static String password = "EncryptionSecretKey" ;
static byte[] salt = "NewSaltTest".getBytes() ;
static int iterCount = 12288 ;
static int derivedKeyLength = 256 ;
public static SecretKey encryptionKey;

public static SecretKey generateSecretKey(){
    SecretKey key=null;
    try {
        salt=Arrays.copyOf(salt,128);
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterCount, derivedKeyLength * 8);
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGO_VIDEO_ENCRYPTOR);
        key = skf.generateSecret(spec);
       }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return key;
}


public static String encryptString(SecretKey key, String input)
{
    byte[] encrypted=null;
    try {
        byte[] iv = new byte[] { (byte) 0x8E, 0x12, 0x39, (byte) 0x9C,
                0x07, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x5A, (byte) 0x8E, 0x12, 0x39, (byte) 0x9C,
                0x07, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x5A };
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        PBEParameterSpec parameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterCount, ivSpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO_VIDEO_ENCRYPTOR);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,parameterSpec);
        String charSet = "UTF-8";
        byte[] in = input.getBytes(charSet);
        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(in);
    }  finally {
        String encStr = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encrypted));
        return encStr;
    }
}

public static String decryptString(SecretKey key, String input) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] decrypted=null;
    try {
        byte[] iv = new byte[] { (byte) 0x8E, 0x12, 0x39, (byte) 0x9C,
                0x07, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x5A, (byte) 0x8E, 0x12, 0x39, (byte) 0x9C,
                0x07, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x5A };
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        PBEParameterSpec parameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterCount, ivSpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO_VIDEO_ENCRYPTOR);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, parameterSpec);
        byte[] enc = Base64.getDecoder().decode(input);
        decrypted = cipher.doFinal(enc);
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Decrypt error"+e);
    }finally {
        String charSet = "UTF-8";
        String plainStr = new String(decrypted, charSet);
        return plainStr;
    }
}
```

I am aware that the equivalence of this algorithm will basically derive a 256-bit AES key using salted PBKDF2 and then encrypt the stored key using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding with that key. (ref - https://neilmadden.blog/2017/11/17/java-keystores-the-gory-details/)

Comment: Kindly note that Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Kindy edit your question and the code you have writen so far and struggling with, thanks.

Comment: Okay, now we see your Java code (b.t.w. that uses **UNSECURE** fixed salt and initialization vector) - where is your NodeJs code you are struggling with?